# Screenshot Notification requiring permission when clicked, but not when using Notification Share action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

This looks like a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198530) (in Marshmallow) but, regardless, it needs to be worked around anyway.

Nexus 6P (6.0.1). Two scenarios:

1. take a screenshot / click on the notification's Share action / share to your app

An ACTION_SEND intent is delivered to the app and the app is (seemingly) granted permission to grab the image (which is specified in mClipData, not mData)

2. take a screenshot / click on the notification itself / share to your app

An ACTION_VIEW intent is delivered to the app, but the app does not have permission (unless already granted READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) because attempting to grab the image (which is specified in mData, not mClipData) gives:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/1234 from pid=12345, uid=23456 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Is there a way to work around this issue without resorting to the app itself requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you open the image from the activity, not from the source/directory file. Or if you want to open from the source you need to add the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the android manifest.

Comment: This question is only regarding the notification. Hangouts does not require the permission when using the Share button, for example.